# VBA ByRef argument acting differently whether passed by parenthesis or not

Tags: vba, arguments, expression, byref, byval

Just regarding passing arguments in vba, ByRef seems to act differently if the argument is passed in parenthesis rather than explicitly stating them using ':=' for example:

```
Sub CallingProcedure()
    Dim a As Long
    a = 123
    CalledProcedure (a)
    MsgBox (a)
    CalledProcedure x:=a
    MsgBox (a)
End Sub

Sub CalledProcedure(ByRef x As Long)
    x = 321
End Sub
```

The first MessageBox will show 123, while the second will show 321. I can't find anywhere explaining why there is a difference in passing the arguments in parenthesis or with ':=". Does anyone know why?

Comment: See Floris' answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls

Comment: Floris's answer is very good @TimWilliams. Thanks for pointing it out.