# Why aren't parentheses required for add method of dictionary class?

Tags: vba, dictionary, excel-2007

The VBA syntax for the add method of the dictionary class is given as:

```
Dictionary.Add (Key as String, Item as Variant)
```

But actually including these parentheses generates a syntax error.

So if D is an object of type dictionary, then vba expects:
D.Add "key1", "value1"

and not:

D.Add("key1", "value1")  <= this generates an error!

Contrasting the Add method with Exists:

```
Dictionary.Exists (Key as String)
```

The parentheses are actually expected:

V1 = D.Exists("key1")

So why is it that the Add syntax specifies ()'s, but doesn't actually expect them (and even generates an error if they are used), while the Exists syntax specifies them and does actually expect them?

Comment: I think VBA uses the same rules as VBScript. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls

Comment: The example you just gave says not to use ()'s if no arguments to a sub, but to use ()'s if there are arguments.  In the Add example above, there are arguments key1, value1.  So ()'s should be expected according to that example, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, if you call a Sub with parameters, you can call it either with:

```
YourSub Parameter1
```

or

```
Call YourSub(Parameter1)
```

Note that `YourSub (Parameter1)` will actually cast Parameter1 to a string and then hand it over to YourSub - which is most certainly not what you want!!!

In case it is a Function, you would call it:

```
result = YourFunction(Parameter1)
```

In case of a Dictionary object, `.Add` is a method/sub, i.e. you use `dict.Add Key, Value`, while `.Exists` is a function, so you need to use `if dict.Exist(Key)...`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying subs vs functions.  That seems to answer the question.  I'll mark as answered in 5 minutes when it will let me.  Silly time delay.  :-)

Comment: So, why doesn't the syntax specify: Dictionary.Add Key, Value telling the programmer not to use ()'s instead of Dictionary.Add (Key, Value)?

Comment: My favorite explanation is this [Daily Dose of Excel post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference Doug.

Comment: @tgoneil: I don't know. Which "syntax" are you referring to exactly?

Comment: As noted initially, Dictionary.Add (Key as String, Item as Variant)

Comment: i meant, where exactly do you see this syntax? in the help file/MSDN/etc.?

Comment: @PeterAlbert:  Apparently the motobit reference is wrong.  MSDN's version has no ()'s for add -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006%28v=vs.60%29.aspx  Wished I'd seen this reference in the first place.  Would have saved me from starting this entire conversation.