# Please explain the role of parenthesis in worksheet.add method

Tags: excel, vba

While writing this code

```
Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

VBA gives option of left parenthesis after the ADD method. But if I enclose

```
after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

in parenthesis is shows an error.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is behind this difference in parentheses effect in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747604/what-is-behind-this-difference-in-parentheses-effect-in-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't parentheses required for add method of dictionary class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126312/why-arent-parentheses-required-for-add-method-of-dictionary-class)

Comment: As mentioned in the SO question I cited above, my favorite discussion of this is this [Daily Dose of Excel post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Comment: Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

One use is to set a variable on-the-fly.

```
dim nuws as worksheet
set nuws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
```

Because you are doing something with the returned value (e.g. setting it to a var), the parameters are required to be in parenthesis.

Another use is to rename the new worksheet in-line.

```
Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "New WS"
```

Again, because you are doing something to the object newly created (e.g. naming it), the parameters are required to be in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Call Worksheets.Add as a sub. No error.

```
Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

Call Worksheets.Add as a function but not using the returned value. Produces error. Basically, you're telling it to return a value but giving it nowhere to store that value.

```
Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
```

Call Worksheets.Add as a function and ignore the returned value. No error.

```
Call Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
```

Call Worksheets.Add as a function and capture the returned value. No error.

```
SomeVar = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
```