# Getting "Expected =" when using Range().Replace()

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a dynamic workbook where I have two Workbooks: one that contains my VB code, and a second containing the Sheets.

As they drop down regions it will update the value depending on the Regions, then update the rest of the Cells.

```
Sub Retrieve_Sales()
    Dim OldRegin As String  // Range [support_NP_E10_T12_CP1a_T12-Regions.xlsx]Region 1'!$B$2 
    Dim NewRegion As String // drop down with Regions 1 - Regions 20

    OldRegion = Range("F2").Select
    NewRegion = Range("C4").Select

    Application.StatusBar = "Retrieing data on" & NewRegion
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("F2").Replace(OldRegion, NewRegion)
End Sub
```

I keep receiving `Expected =`. Am I suppose to wrap it to a variable?

Answer (score 3):

You might have several issues.

First, for the Expected = message change the `.Replace` line to:

```
Range("F2").Replace OldRegion, NewRegion
```

For more details, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519085/2258

Also, I expected you want the `.Value` of the `Range`, not the `.Select`

```
OldRegion = Range("F2").Value
NewRegion = Range("C4").Value
```

Comment: Almost, you corrected some of my mistake.  Now im going to make a small change i noticed to Range should be E3:F19.  As i made the change [support_NP_E10_T12_CP1a_T12-Regions.xlsx]Region 1'!$B$2 region is not updating to what variable i'm updating to.

Comment: Thank you i found out my problem..., missed misspelled the variables.