# Coding Array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code to remove duplicates in Excel:

```
    AlertRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, _
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, _
    34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49), Header:=xlNo
```

It works fine. But could there be a better way to provide the array to the "Columns" parameter? The way it codes looks stupid.

Comment: `Array(1:49)`? or `Array("1:49")` Unsure if that works the same as `Range()` or `Columns()`

Comment: @Chrismas007 - tried both but seems the syntax not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since *RemoveDuplicates* wants a *Variant,* zero-based, array rather than a *Range* you could make it with a loop:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim ary(0 To 48)

    For i = 0 To 48
        ary(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    Range("$A$1:$BB$20").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BB$20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ary), Header _
        :=xlNo
End Sub
```

Please note the **(ary)** 
 This is to accommodate a very old VBA bug.

Comment: +1 good point with the (ary). For more info this might be usefull [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls).

Comment: @Gary'sStudent... thx! i make it become a small routine to generate the array.