# Compile error calling a Sub Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA but years of experience with assembler, C and C#.  I have created a Private Sub called CPScenarioData(wsname as String, rownum As Integer).  When I call the procedure using the statement:

```
 CPScenarioData(wsname, l)
```

I get an error 'Compile error: Expected =', however when I preceded the statement with Call no error occurs, why is this.  I have other Private subs that I call without using Call that work fine.  I am sure there is a simple answer or mistake I have made and will feel very sheepish when I see the answer but that's life.  I am using Excel 2013 VBA.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Lose the parentheses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules governing usage of brackets in VBA function calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls)

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk (feature according to taste) of VB.  To call a sub, you don't include brackets.  So simply type:

```
CPScenarioData wsname, 1
```

Normally brackets are used to denote a Function, which returns a value.  In VB you must provide a variable to receive the returned value. (Hence the compile error for missing =; it is expecting a = CPScenario(wsname, 1)).

Adding the word Call enables you to keep the brackets for Subs (equivalent of c# void).

Comment: Huh, I always got the same error and did not know the reason. Thanks!