# Excel vba runtime error 424 Object required when assigning Range variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that consists of a function and subroutine that uses that function. Function takes a column as an argument and alters each of that column cell's content.

```
Function testFunc(aCol As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each cell In aCol
        cell.Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Function


Sub testSub()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A16")

    testFunc (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A16"))   '<--- this works fine
    testFunc (aRange)    '<---- error
End Sub
```

The `Runtime error '424' Object required"| arises on line`testFunc (aRange)`. I'm not sure what's wrong, I assign variable through 'Set' and it's supposed to work fine.

Also, I tried passing the range directly to the function, without storing it in the variable first and it workes perfectly. **Why**?

Comment: Don't wrap the parameter in brackets.  have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls

Comment: @sous2817, Ok. But it doesn't seem to explain why in the first case it workes fine (see edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses around an expression are causing the expression to be evaluated **as a value** and passed `ByVal` to the procedure invoked.

> ```
> testFunc (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A16"))   '<--- this works fine
> ```

No, it doesn't work fine, not with `aCol As Range` in the signature of `testFunc` - for the exact same reason as the line underneath it. A `Range` object has a *default member* that points to its `.Value`. When you do this:

```
DoSomething (SomeRange)
```

What's really happening is this:

```
DoSomething (SomeRange.Value)
```

The parentheses are telling VBA to *evaluate the expression as a value*, **before** passing the result **by value** (`ByVal`) of that expression to the procedure being invoked, *regardless* of the implicit `ByRef` modifier in the procedure's signature.

Problem is, given a 16-cell `Range`, `Range.Value` is a 2D array - and given a single-cell `Range`, `Range.Value` is a `Variant` that contains that cell's value, *and that can't possibly be coerced into a `Range` object instance*, so it's impossible that the code you have here "works fine": it's an *object required* error, because the procedure is expecting a `Range` and you're giving it a `Variant` that contains a 2D array.

---

#### Why your "works fine" code isn't really working

The only way `testFunc (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A16"))` could possibly work, is if `testFunc` had this signature (which, I suspect it did at one point before you ultimately asked this question):

```
Function testFunc(aCol)
```

Or the explicit equivalent:

```
Public Function testFunc(ByRef aCol As Variant) As Variant
```

And because a 2D array *can* be iterated with a `For Each` loop ([albeit very inefficiently](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)), and it's possible that the entire `A1:A16` range contains values that *can* be coerced into valid `Integer` values, "works fine" indeed... except you're **updating an in-memory copy of the data, not the cells themselves** - so it wasn't quite "works fine", was more like "doesn't crash".

Here's a MCVE:

```
Private Function DoSomething(ByRef foo As Range)
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    DoSomething (Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

Calling `Test` throws run-time error 424 "Object Required".

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef foo As Range)
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    DoSomething (Range("A1:A100").Value)
End Sub
```

Calling `Test` throws the same run-time error 424 "Object Required".

Now remove the `As Range` declaration:

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef foo As Variant)
    Debug.Print TypeName(foo)
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    DoSomething (Range("A1:A100").Value)
End Sub
```

Invoking `Test` prints `Variant()` to the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G). Now make the range contain just one single cell:

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef foo As Variant)
    Debug.Print TypeName(foo)
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    DoSomething (Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

Invoking `Test` prints whatever data type the value of cell A1 holds. If it's text, it prints `String`. If it's a number, it prints `Double`. If it's a date, it prints `Date`. If it's a cell error (e.g. `#NA`, `#VALUE!`, etc.), it prints `Error`.

Note that the results are identical for all of the above, whether you specify `.Value` explicitly or not, because omitting `.Value` boils down to implicitly specifying it.

Also note that passing an array `ByVal` is illegal. What's being passed to the function here is a **copy** of *a pointer to the beginning of the array* - the `Variant` array isn't storing the array itself, just a pointer to its actual location: that's why & how you can legally pass a variant array by value.

---

#### Why the variable is blowing up too

The 2nd line is throwing the same error, for the same reason:

> ```
> testFunc (aRange)    '<---- error
> ```

You're implicitly doing this:

```
testFunc aRange.Value
```

Because that's what the parentheses do: they tell VBA to *evaluate the expression as a value, and pass it as such*.

So you're passing a 2D variant array to a procedure that's expecting a `Range`.

This is different, and correct:

```
testFunc aRange
```

Note the lack of parentheses: now you're passing the `Range` object reference to a procedure that accepts a `Range` object reference, `ByRef` (although that modifier is implicit and a more semantically correct way to do it would be to pass the object reference `ByVal`).

---

#### So how do I tell when the arguments are being evaluated as a value?

When you invoke a `Function` procedure, you're normally interested in its *return value*:

```
result = MsgBox("Confirm?", vbYesNo)
```

The VBA automatically positions the opening parenthesis immediately after the function's identifier - no whitespace.

When you invoke a `Function` procedure without capturing its return value, you must omit the parentheses:

```
MsgBox "Confirm?", vbYesNo
```

Note that this would be a compile error:

```
MsgBox ("Confirm?", vbYesNo)
```

Because the expression `("Confirm?", vbYesNo)` cannot be evaluated as a value and passed as such to the first parameter of the procedure.

That's easy though - `MsgBox` has multiple parameters. People get confused when there's only one parameter - because then this *looks* legal:

```
testFunc (aRange)
```

**Notice the whitespace: it shouldn't be there**. That's the VBE telling you *"these parentheses are NOT part of the function call, they're part of the argument you're going pass to that function, and if whatever is in these parentheses can't be evaluated as a value at run-time, expect trouble"*.

---

If your `testFunc` procedure isn't *returning a value*, then it shouldn't be a `Function` in the first place - it should be a `Sub` procedure. Functions take input and return a value, Subs *do something*, which usually entails side-effects, e.g. actual cell values being modified.

Comment: this answer is really great :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code woubl to be lik this.

```
Sub testFunc(aCol As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each cell In aCol
        cell.Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub


Sub testSub()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A16")

    testFunc aRange    '<---- error
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse me, did you change anything?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However it-s just a simplified example of a bigger program, I would really rather use function, why isn't this possible here and if there some other way arounf it?

Comment: @Ans: you can use function.

Comment: @Ans A `Function` should return something, a `Sub` should be a procedure with no return value. _Theoretically_ there's nothing stopping you from using them interchangeably - but it's bad practice and confusing to do so in VBA