# VBA: Move Mail from Junk to Inbox

Tags: vba, email, move

I'm trying to move all my junk mail to my inbox by VBA code. Unfortunately i get an '424 object required' error on this line:

```
    Item.Move (olFLD)
```

The code works when i try to move mail from inbox to another folder but it doesn't work the other way around when i try to move a mail from junk to the inbox.

```
Dim OlNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFLD As Outlook.Folder
Dim olJunk As Outlook.Folder

Sub Junk()

Set OlNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFLD = OlNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olJunk = OlNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)

While olJunk.Items.Count <> 0

For Each Item In olJunk.Items

Item.Move (olFLD)

Next

Wend

End Sub
```

Does anyone have an answer to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis are weird in vba. When you call a function from an object where you're not expecting a return value, you'd leave off the parenthesis.

```
Item.Move olFLD
```

Alternatively, to avoid confusion as to when and when not to use parenthesis, you can preface functions with `Call`

```
Call Item.Move(olFLD)
```

Read more:
[What are the rules governing usage of brackets in VBA function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `()`

```
Item.Move olFLD
```

Source:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-move-method-outlook

Comment: Thanks for your reply this was indeed the solution!