# Excel VBA Replace Function and Parameter

Tags: excel, vba

the following code works:

```
Dim strNew As String
strNew = "xxyy"
strNew = Replace (strNew, "y", "z")
```

But this one doesn't, i get a syntax error:

```
Dim strNew As String
strNew = "xxyy"
strNew = Replace expression:=strNew, find:="y", replace:="z"
```

This is the description of the Replace Function (part of vba.strings) according to "help" (F2):

> Function Replace(Expression As String, Find As String, Replace As
> String, [Start As Long = 1], [Count As Long = -1], [Compare As
> VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare]) As String
>
> Element von VBA.Strings
>
> Find and replace a substring within a string

I don't understandy why there is an error?

Comment: You took the brackets out...

Comment: When you call a function/procedure you can pass it's arguments without brackets, but if you are giving it to a variable, you must use brackets.

Comment: You could still do `strNew = Replace(expression:=strNew, find:="y", replace:="z")` or `strNew = Replace strNew, "y", "z"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules governing usage of brackets in VBA function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls)