# Object doesn't support this property or method, If I declare variable with correct type

Tags: excel, vba

I declare 2 ClassModules:

**Class1**

```
Public MyProp As Class2
Public Sub MyMethod(val As Class2)
    Set MyProp = val
    MsgBox MyProp.Foo
End Sub
```

**Class2**

```
Public Foo As String
```

**Sheet1**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Class1
    Dim b As Class2

    Set a = New Class1
    Set b = New Class2

    b.Foo = "Bar"

    a.MyMethod (b)

End Sub
```

When I call a.MyMethod (b), I get "Object doesn't support this property or method"

but if I write the code as following, everything works as expected:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant

    Set a = New Class1
    Set b = New Class2

    b.Foo = "Bar"

    a.MyMethod (b)

End Sub
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong syntax:  `a.MyMethod b`  works.

Comment: So if I declare the type I cant use parentheses? Sorry I am not VBA expert

Comment: Parentheses are generally used when setting one value equal to another.You are not doing that when calling your class method.  Another option would be using the `Call` method as in `Call a.MyMethod(b)`.  With `Call`, the argument list needs to be in parentheses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls

Comment: `a.method(b)`passes b as byval argument instead of being a byref argument, but it shouldn't raise an error here. Instead, what is concerning me is `Set MyProp = val` wich cannot be done : you need to copy each variable from the class. In this case easily enough `MyProp.foo = val.foo`. Often VBA doesn't give the right error line (place a breakpoint on a.method(b), you'll see it goes there and errors later)