# Standard function use in VBA - how do you write it? With brackets or with spaces?

Tags: vba

I watch VBA tutorials by WiseOwl - e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q - and I noticed that he writes functions, he is inconsistent. When he uses `Offset`, he always writes it this way: `Offset(1, 0)` - with brackets. When he writes `MsgBox`, he writes `MsgBox "Message"` - with space, without brackets. What is the standard way of using functions in VBA? Using brackets is consistent with other programming languages, but if others will frown upon me because I use them instead of spaces, then I'll adjust.

Another thing I'd like to ask about additionally is how do you execute a function which has got many arugments and which you want to write in more than one line, hitting enter. Underscore doesn't work, so there's probably another magic key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls

Comment: For a line continuation, use a space and then underscore.