# Excel VBA - Sheets.Printout I dont know why it works but still throws an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works, but throws a

```
"Run-time '1004' Unable to set the Printout property of the worksheet class"
```

Here's the code:

```
Sub PrintOutv1()

'PrintOutv1 Macro
Dim Val As Double
Val = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WU").Range("E1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WU").PrintOut(1, Val, 1, True) = True
```

Comment: Side note, don't use `Val` as a variable name, because of the [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function.

Comment: Drop the `= True`.

Comment: The = True is necessary

Comment: [Is it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.printout)? Drop the parentheses too.

Comment: I think it has to do with passing 'val' into the parentheses after Printout()

Comment: If you drop it, it gives "expected a '='"

Comment: Drop the parentheses as well.

Comment: Update: Neither changing the variable name, as well as dropping the =True, work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses bite again! Drop the parentheses around the arguments and don't attempt to assign a value:

```vb
Dim myVal As Double '<~ avoid confusion with the Val function
myVal = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WU").Range("E1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WU").PrintOut 1, myVal, 1, True
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls